# Visual studio code c# intellisense not working as expected

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Hello recently I started using only visual studio code for my .net core 2 project.
The problem I have found is the intellisense not working as i expect in vs code.

Always after using '.' to access avaible methods and properties no suggestions appear I have to push "ctrl+space" for them to appear.

And when I push "ctrl+space" it comes with suggestions that I can't use for anything.
[Linq Example for none working intellisense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ndsmx.png)

Same happens when I try to access the properties of a class.

Is it possible to get intellisense that work like in normal visual studio? I have installed C# extension for debugging and intellisense.
[Proof of installed plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYt3H.png)

Comment: I've never had that problem, but you won't get VS IntelliSense quality in VSCode.

Comment: Hmm will try a reinstall of vs code and see if I messed up anything on the way. Everything else works just fine, but a bit of a pain to code without the intellisense :D